# How can I apply a style to all inputs that are text and dont have the "size" attribute?

Tags: html, css

I have this style:

```
input[type=text], textarea {
    width: 98%;
    border: 1px #999 solid;
}
```

It applies the width to all the input that are text but how can I exclude the ones that have the attribute size? I tried `input[type=text],input[size!=2], textarea` but it doesnt work.

Thanks!!

Comment: You will need to either remove the size attribute or use JavaScript to update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask for a `CSS3` solution you may use `:not` pseudoclass

```
input[type=text]:not([size]), textarea {
   width: 98%;
   border: 1px #999 solid;
}
```

Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KFped/

---

if you want instead to support older browsers (like `IE8`) just apply a style for

```
input[type=text], textarea {
   width: 98%;
   border: 1px #999 solid;
}
```

and thus revert the style for

```
input[type=text][size] {
   /* revert properties */
}
```